# Regular expression exact match of a word or a phrase

Tags: jquery, regex, match

I need to get a match only if the given word or phrase is present.

```
My name is Kristina      :- match
Here is Kristinatt       :- not a match
Kristina is coming       :- match
Akristina is not a name  :- not a match
Kristina is a good name  :- match
```

Here is my jQuery code

```
var needle = "Kristina";
var haystack = "Here is Kristinatt";
var search_regexp = new RegExp('\\b' + needle + '\\b', "gi");
if(haystack.match(search_regexp) != null){
    alert("match found");
}else{
    alert("no match found");
}
```

Ideally I should get no match found for the mentioned needle and haystack combination. Any thoughts on what I could have done wrong?

Comment: I _do_ get 'no match found'

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working check that:
http://jsfiddle.net/yvq2tk7n

Another solution:

```
var needle = "Kristina",
    haystack = "Here is Kristinatt",
    check = haystack.split(/\s+|\./).includes(needle);
if(check){
    alert("match found");
}else{
    alert("no match found");
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvq2tk7n/1/

If that's not what you mean, Please clarify what you are seeking for.